# Using context beans within a Condition or a ConfigurationCondition

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I wish to use a org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition interface to disable/enable at startup some of my @Configuration classes. Example below:

```
public class Condition implements ConfigurationCondition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        //Gets the configuration manager from the context
        RapidConfDocConfiguration.DocConf docConf = context.getBeanFactory().getBean(DocConf.class);

        return docConf.isEnabled();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfDocConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DocConf docConf() {
        return new DocConf(true);
    }
}

@Configuration
@Import(ConfDocConfiguration.class)
@Conditional({Condition.class})
public class RapidSwaggerConfiguration {
    //Some configurations
}
```

The problem i have here is that the Condition is executed before that any of the context is instantiated and then the 'DocConf' is not yet present. The Condition works well if i read an environment variable or something like that.

So, is it possible to use this kind of condition based on a spring bean of the context ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible because your DocConf class is not loaded as a Configuration, @Bean annotated beans are created after all configuration is done.

For this to work, your DocConf class would have to be added to the context as a Spring configuration, so including it via @Bean from a different configuration cannot work, because non-configuration Beans are only created after the configuration phase.

Consider this article: http://www.javarticles.com/2016/01/spring-configuration-condition-example.html

Another example at  http://javapapers.com/spring/spring-conditional-annotation/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 

The DocConf bean is indeed in another @Configuration.

I tested with the ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN and the code: 'context.getBeanFactory().containsBeanDefinition("docConf")' returns true like in the article.
The definition of the bean is present in the context but the bean itself is not: 'context.getBeanFactory().getBean("docConf")' throws a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

My purpose here is to be able to interract with the bean instance itself.

I could use a profile but for some reason inherent to my project, i can not use spring profiles.

Comment: It might help to know how you add the DocConf configuration to the context (e.g. via @Import or @ComponentScan).

Comment: @Import to the configuration class which defines it. But i've tried with a component scan also.