# Is it possible to use lambda in SpEL inside @ConditionalOnExpression

Tags: java, spring-boot, lambda, spring-el

Is it possible to use `lambda` for`@ConditionalOnExpression` in spring expression language (SpEL)?
I have created the following SpEL condition via [collection-selection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-collection-selection) which works fine for me. But I am not satisfied how it looks like.

```
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{T(java.util.Arrays).asList('${app.sync.white-list}').?[#this.toLowerCase() == 'all' or #this.toLowerCase() == 'phone'].size() > 0}")
```

In `Java` the logic for the condition is the following:

```
Arrays.stream(a).anyMatch(x -> "all".equalsIgnoreCase(x) || "phone".equalsIgnoreCase(x))
```

I wonder if it is possible to make that SpEL condition look nicer via using `anyMatch` and `lambda`?

Comment: Is there any reason to turn configuration into puzzle? Just implement your own org.springframework.context.annotation.Condition.

Comment: Using `Condition` is limited in practice by using  `profiles` only. And in my case, I cannot use `profiles` due to the project restriction. `Condition`  does not allow to access to the bean values.  As the beans are present but not yet initialized https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46481117/using-context-beans-within-a-condition-or-a-configurationcondition
That is why I came to `@ConditionalOnExpression`, which though looks ugly. And I just want to make it prettier.

Comment: `@ConditionalOnExpression` (actually `OnExpressionCondition`) does not have any advantages over implementing `Condition`: it uses the same, partially constructed `context.getBeanFactory()`, if you observe desired behaviour in one case and do not observe the same in another case it is just a matter of time when everything will "suddenly" stop working as expected.

Comment: SpEL means Spring Expression **Language** - it is **not** java and so there should be no expectation that it supports lambdas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to over-complicate SpEL: just have that logic in some `static` method and use it via `T` operator: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-types. Or you can register it as a function in the `EvaluationContext`. See same doc.

The point is that SpEL is an interpreted language: the longer and and complex expression - the slower calculation.